# How to change a character in a specific line of a file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a .bd document which has lines for each book that I have. Each book has the title, author, etc divided by a `\t`. The last character of each line can be 1 or 0 depending on whether the book is borrowed or not. I need a way to change that number change the state of a book by using the id (first number of the line).

```
1   title1  author1 genre1  year1   shelv1  0
2   title2  author2 genre2  year2   shelv2  0
3   title3  author3 genre3  year3   shelv3  0
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change status of id 2 to 1:

```
awk -v id=2 -v status=1 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} $1==id {$NF=status}1' file
```

Output:

```
1       title1  author1 genre1  year1   shelv1  0
2       title2  author2 genre2  year2   shelv2  1
3       title3  author3 genre3  year3   shelv3  0
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: And what about increasing or decreasing the value instead of assigning a specific value to it.

By the way, thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: That would probably also be possible. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55561164/3776858) might help.

Answer (score 1):

based on the assumption that all ids are integers:

```sh
$ awk -v ids='1 3' '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
ids~"(^| )"$1"( |$)"{$NF=!$NF}
1' file
1       title1  author1 genre1  year1   shelv1  1
2       title2  author2 genre2  year2   shelv2  0
3       title3  author3 genre3  year3   shelv3  1
```

to update `file` with above command's output:

```
awk ... file > tmpfile && mv tmpfile file
```

---

note that above script is not scalable at all, it will take too much time to process a file consisting of >1000 lines. if you need an efficient one and won't mind its length, here it is:

```
awk -v ids='1 3' '
BEGIN {
  split(ids,p)
  for(i in p) q[p[i]]
  FS=OFS="\t"
}
($1 in q) {
  $NF=!$NF
}
1' file
```

I also wrote one that doesn't create two arrays but then thought it isn't worth it.