# How to change a word of a particular line in a text?

Tags: bash

I am changing the last word of a particular line in a text.
This word can be repeated in other lines.

What command can I use for this?

```
# file libros.bd 
while IFS = read line
   do
     word=$(echo $line|rev|cut -f1 -d' '|rev) #Last word in each line
done <"$file"
```

**This is my input file:**

> 18654 "JuanFrances" autor1 1964 1 no
>
> 18655 "Lucas Tercero" autor2 1987 2 si
>
> 18656 "Fernando Emperador" autor3 1845 5 no
>
> 18657 "Juan Fernando" autor3 1965 1 si

**This would be the final state**

> 18654 "JuanFrances" autor1 1964 1 no
>
> 18655 "Lucas Tercero" autor2 1987 2 si
>
> 18656 "Fernando Emperador" autor3 1845 5 no
>
> 18657 "Juan Fernando" autor3 1965 1 **no**

**This would be one way**

> sed ''"$line"'s/no/si/' libros.bd > temp && mv temp libros.bd

Comment: See: [How to change a character in a specific line of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55557903/3776858)

Comment: what are you basing your change on?

Comment: When you say "my output file", do you really mean "my input file"? === When you say "a word", how does the program know which word?  === When you say "a particular line", how does the program know which line? ===  This question is far too vague.  As given, it could be asking how to change the last word in the last line.  Please reword the question, eliminating indefinite articles and giving enough specific details that someone could use it to write a real program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get last word you can use `grep`

```
grep -Eo '[^ ]+$'
```

so in your case:

```
word=$(echo $line| grep -Eo '[^ ]+$')
```

`grep` searches for pattern as you know, `-E` is `--extended-regexp` or more advanced regex mathing. `-o` output matched lines to not color them.

regex part:
`[^ ]` matches space
`+` match previous once or more times
`$` matches end of line

And here is output based on your input:

```
no
si
no
si
state
no
si
no
no
```