# How to increment number in a text

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to increase the last character in the third row

**This is my input file**

```
33981 Juan Robles Garcia 5 1
33982 Lucas Robles Garcia 3 0
33983 Alba Robles Garcia 3 0
```

**This would be the output file**

```
33981 Juan Robles Garcia 5 1
33982 Lucas Robles Garcia 3 0
33983 Alba Robles Garcia 3 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Take a look at [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info).

Comment: I'm trying: awk '{$ 6 + = 1; print $ 0} '$ line> temp && mv temp file; But this command increases all the values in the column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If current row is third row (NR==3) then increment value by one in last column ($NF). In any case, output the whole row (print).

In any case, prints the entire line .

```
awk '{if (NR==3) {$NF++}; {print}}' file
```

or shorter

```
awk 'NR==3 {$NF++} {print}' file
```

or shorter

```
awk 'NR==3 {$NF++}1' file
```

Output:

```
33981 Juan Robles Garcia 5 1
33982 Lucas Robles Garcia 3 0
33983 Alba Robles Garcia 3 1
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: or even shorter : `awk '($NF+=3~NR)_'`